# Problem with Loading tiny imagenet via torch DataLoader

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision, imagenet

I'm using tiny-imagenet-200 and I'm not sure that loading them with torch.utils.data.DataLoader is possible or not.
I downloaded tiny-imagenet-200 from Stanford site, but the format of validation set in a directory with name val_0 to val_9999 and the label of them is in a .txt.
How can I load this directory via torch.utils.data.DataLoader?
I tried:

```
datasets.ImageFolder(args.val_dir, transforms.Compose([
            OpencvResize(256),
            transforms.CenterCrop(224),
            ToBGRTensor(),
        ])
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that using `ImageFolder` directly. There are alternatives, though:

- You can read the annotation file and re-structure the directories to enable the usage of `ImageFolder`, as in [here](https://github.com/tjmoon0104/pytorch-tiny-imagenet/blob/master/val_format.py);
- You can implement a custom `Dataset`. Luckly, as Tiny ImageNet is a popular dataset, you can find many implementations online. For instance, [this one](https://gist.github.com/z-a-f/b862013c0dc2b540cf96a123a6766e54#file-tin-py-L143-L201).

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I can use ImageFolder for reading train dataser, right? Because training set contain some sub directories with special name

Comment: @Arezooabadi yes, you sure can. Only the validation and test sets have different structure that are not supported by ImageFolder.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve it with your proposed methods.